# python class B inherit class A with all its methods but change one method only

Tags: python, methods, overwrite

Let's say class A has 10 methods. Some of the methods are private and it has private attributes as well. I want to create class B so I can change last method only without duplicating the code for the rest of the methods. My example is below. At the moment I am unable to achieve it with such inheritance as I get `AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_B__c'`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.__foo()

    def __foo(self):
        self.__c  = self.a + self.b

    def get_data(self):
        return self.__c


    class B(A):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.__c = self.__modify_data()
    
        def __modify_data(self):
            self.__c += 10000
    
        def get_data(self):
            return self.__c
    
    
    b = B(a=5, b=10).get_data()
```

Question 2:
Can I achieve it with use of *args so I do not have to repeat all the arguments?

EDIT:
Please see my updated code above.
I believe private attributes causes the problem.

Can I solve it with still using private?

Comment: `def __init__(self, *args):` and `super(B, self).__init__(*args)`

Comment: If you want to access your attributes from a child class, you must not give them names starting with double underscores, which makes them private to the class itself.

Comment: @Olvin Roght this gives me: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'

Comment: @jasonharper I want to use them as private for a reason. I know private in python = pseudoprivate (not true private as I can access them anyway) but I want to stick with __private

Comment: @dkrynicki, add one more argument `**kwargs` and pass it to constructor of parent as well.

Comment: I see __private is what causes the problem

Comment: `self.__c = self.__modify_data()` why are you doing this. `self.__c += 10000` won't work. I guess you want something like `self.__c = 0` in the constructor.

Comment: I do this because I want to create private attribute in the class A that is used by get_data() to return its value. I want to create different get_data method in class B.

Comment: Just use names like `_c` and `_modify_data` for "private" attributes.

Comment: Python **doesn't have private variables**. No, it's not "pseudoprivate", **there are no private variables**. This is important to understand. When you use two underscores, you are using *name mangling*. The **only purpose** of name-mangling is to prevent *subclasses from using that attribute*. So stop using two underscores. Non-public parts of the API are conventionally designated with *a single underscore*.

Comment: So in essence, your question amounts to "can I use the language construct that exists for preventing accessing attributes in a subclass while not preventing accessing attributes in a subclass".

Comment: not really. I just want to use base class that uses private attributes and ovewrite last method to modify returned data. I would like to not touch all base class method and all base class attributes apart from one last method and still use private attribute. But it looks like it is not possible.

Comment: @dkrynicki again **python doesn't have private attributes**, so it's impossible to do that, because there are no private attributes. If you are going to use *double-underscore name-mangling*, then **the whole point** is to prevent name-collisions in a subclass. So the superclass constructor intializes it's own version of `self.__c`, which is why you are getting that error, because in `B.__modify_data`, you use `self.__c += 10000` but you can't, *because `self.__c` **isn't defined for `B`*. Because **you** chose to use double-underscore name-mangling to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.__foo()

    def __foo(self):
        self._c  = self.a + self.b

    def get_data(self):
        return self._c


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__modify_data()

    def __modify_data(self):
        self._c += 10000



b = B(a=5, b=10).get_data()
print(b)
```

Output:
`10015`

Changing `_c` to `__c` gives `AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_B__c'`

Yes, the `__` is causing the trouble by making variable `c` inaccessible in children, which is good because the private variable of parents should not be allowed to edit by the children class.